# Method calling in Razor Page doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

It is my page. I have an issue with the button:

```
@page
@model lab2razor_pages.Pages.Products.IndexModel

<h1>Products</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@product.Name</td>
                <td>@product.Description</td>
                <td>@product.Category</td>
                <td>@product.Price</td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-page-handler="AddToCart" method="post" asp-route-productId="@product.Id">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, this is my PageModel class:

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
        {
                
          // remaining code
    
            public IActionResult OnPostAddToCart(int productId)
            {
    
                *... do some code here ...*
    
               
            }
        }
```

The button doesn't call the method OnPostAddToCart - I tried with different names, but it just doesn't call the method.
I didn't copy the code inside the method because I already tried to put a breakpoint on it and it is not being called at all. There is bad request error after you click the button.

Where did I make an error

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: Can you share the rendered HTML for the form mentioned? Would like to check for the form action, method.

Comment: I tried your code in the post and there was no problem. Can you share another section or provide more explanations

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi maybe will be best if you check on github, there is no much code because i just try to learn razor pages so this is my first app

https://github.com/defcon1one1/razor_pages_lab2/tree/master/Pages

I will appreciate if you can take a look. I get bad request for some reason

Comment: @defcon1 , I checked your project and wrote way solve your problem in new answer

Comment: @QingGuo yes, solution in answer below works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems

1. @addTagHelper  inactive(because you use  tag-helpers example asp-page-handler)

You must enable @addTagHelper

Tag helpers are an opt-in feature. They are not available to the page by default. They are enabled by adding an @addTagHelper directive to the page, or more usually to a _ViewImports.cshtml file[Enabling-Tag-Helpers](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers#enabling-tag-helpers)

2.And you should have indexed the name of the action like an action

```
 <form asp-page-handler="AddToCart" method="post" asp-route-productId="@product.Id">
    <button type="submit"  class="btn">Add to Cart</button>
 </form>
```

also,You had a problem on the second page "/Cart/Index" as well. You should use [Include](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx) to solve your problem

My Code

```
 var user = _context.Users.Include(d => d.Cart).ThenInclude(d => d.Products).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == userId);
```

Your Code

```
   var user = _context.Users.Find(userId);
```

Comment: Perfect, this has resolved my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the  tag. You forgot to add the "asp-route-productID" attribute. You need to add this attribute to pass the product ID to the AddToCart method on the server.
Here's how it should look like:

```html
<button type="submit" asp-page-handler="addToCart" asp-route-productId="@product.id" class="btn">Add to Cart</button>
```

Note that I replaced the space between "asp-" and "route-productid" with a hyphen "-" to avoid a conflict with the "class" attribute of the  tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't call the method. I even tried deleting the productId parameter altogether, but the method simply doesn't get called regardless. It's strange given the fact I did it exactly as it is in MS documentation or any tutorial